# If a1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ∈ 0 ≤ a ≤ 1, prove that 1(1 − 2) + 2(1 − 3) + 3(1 − 4) + 4(1 − 5) + 5(1 − 6) + 6(1 − 1) ≤ 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It looks obvious but I'm not sure how to approach it mathematically and prove it.

If a1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ∈ 0 ≤ a ≤ 1, prove that 1(1 − 2) + 2(1 − 3) + 3(1 − 4) + 4(1 − 5) + 5(1 − 6) + 6(1 − 1) ≤ 3

So I first thought about only assigning 1's and 0's. If we did that, in order to make one of the equations (ax(1-ay)) = 1, ax needs to be assigned 1 and ay needs to be assigned 0, assigning ax 1 will make (ab(1-ax)) = 0, also assigning ay 0 will make (ay(1-ac)) = 0, so in order to make one equation equal to 1 we need to make 2 equal to 0, but I'm not sure how to continue

Comment: It would be nice if you could phrase the question more neatly, not just in the title.

Comment: It is easy to prove that $$a_1 (1 - a_2) + a_2 (1 - a_3) + a_3 (1 - a_4) + a_4 (1 - a_5) + a_5 (1 - a_6) + a_6 (1 - a_1) \leq 6,$$
if $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6 \in [0,1]$.  I do not currently see a way on how to improve that upper bound to $\leq 3$.

Comment: Sorry about phrasing the question very bad, I edited the question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Pick any $a_i$ (assume the others are fixed), the LHS is linear, so maximum is when $a_i \in \{0, 1\}$.